# Is it possible to reinstall an android that has a pass lock?

Tags: installation, password, uninstallation

I bought a new **Sony Xperia Z C6603** phone last week and first thing I did was set a complex pass code. Unfortunately I forgot it shortly after and now I have no access to the phone. Is there a way to reinstall the entire operating system so I can start new and have no pass code?

Answer (score 0):

That won't be necessary.

Open up the Android device manager on a PC or Mac and log in to your google account. If you mark the device as lost, you can set a temporary password. Use the temp password to get past your lock screen, then promptly go to the settings and change your password back.

Also, after 5 failed attempts of entering the password your device should let you override it with your Google password.

Comment: And if that doesn't work there is always the ability to reset the phone (Last resort)

Comment: @Matt07211 let's hope it doesn't come to that.